# UIScrollView is not scrolling till the end of the child UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, storyboard, uistackview

I have a UIScrollView which has a UIStackView as it's child.

I want to link it's scroll to the size of the internal stack view so that it is able to scroll to the bottom of it.

I have tried many other approaches like

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackViewMain.frame.width, height: stackViewMain.frame.height)
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

or

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: stackViewMain.frame.width, height: 1000)
```

I have even tried hardcoding the height of scrollView in the storyboard. But it still scrolls a very small amount and not more than that.

I have already added the edge contraints for both the views

[image]
[image]

What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be constraining the four edges of the stack view to the four edges of the scroll view. Autolayout sets the scroll view's `contentSize` based on the constraints between the scroll view and its descendants.

More info: [Technical Note TN2154: UIScrollView And Autolayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2154/_index.html)

Comment: The constraints are already in place. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

@Saad Qureshi, You can try **ScrollableStackView** : https://github.com/gurhub/ScrollableStackView

**Sample Code (Swift)**

```
import ScrollableStackView

var scrollable = ScrollableStackView(frame: view.frame)
view.addSubview(scrollable)

// add your views with 
let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 55))
rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
scrollable.stackView.addArrangedSubview(rectangle)
// ...
```

**Sample Code (Objective-C)**

```
@import ScrollableStackView

ScrollableStackView *scrollable = [[ScrollableStackView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scrollable.stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
scrollable.stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;
scrollable.stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
[self.view addSubview:scrollable];

UIView *rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 55)];
[rectangle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

// add your views with
[scrollable.stackView addArrangedSubview:rectangle]; 
// ...
```

Let me know if it helps.